# Object not visible when making child of a camera in three.js

Tags: three.js, camera, parent-child

I am a beginner to three.js. I am trying to make a sphere a child of my camera in my scene. But the sphere doesn't appear in the scene anywhere. I assumed that the position of the sphere is set in such a way that it is behind or above the camera so it isn't visible because it moves with the camera.

But I tried using a second camera in order to view where the object is with respect to the first camera but the sphere isn't visible anywhere in the scene.

The sphere is visible when I don't make it a child of the camera.

Is there an easier way to do it or an I missing something.

Comment: Add the camera to the scene, add the sphere to the camera.

Answer (score 2):

The camera must be added to the scene graph if the camera has a (renderable) child.

The camera looks down its local negative-z axis, so to ensure the child is visible, set the z-coordinate of the child's position to a negative value.

```
scene.add( camera );
camera.add( child );
child.position.set( 0, 0, - 100 );
```

three.js r.94

Comment: This solved my problem. Thankyou so much. Though I would like to know if there is an easier way to see an object that is not being rendered by the camera. .

Comment: An object that is not part of the scene graph will not be rendered.